# chefでffmpegをインストールする際にコンパイルオプションを変更する

Tags: chef

ffmpegを[このcookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ffmpeg)を用いてインストールしようとした所 x264 のコンパイルに失敗したため検索して出てきた解決策の「コンパイル時に `--enable-static` を追加する。」というのを実行するために下記の配列を`ubuntu.json` に追記しました。

```
"ffmpeg": {
    "compile_flags": [
    "--disable-debug",
    "--enable-pthreads",
    "--enable-nonfree",
    "--enable-gpl",
    "--disable-indev=jack",
    "--enable-libx264",
    "--enable-libfaac",
    "--enable-libmp3lame",
    "--enable-libtheora",
    "--enable-libvorbis",
    "--enable-libvpx",
    "--enable-libxvid",
    "--enable-libfaad",
    "--enable-static"
    ]
  },
```

これで x264 のインストールは正常に行えたのですがデフォルトの値を全て再定義するのはできれば避けたいので`default['ffmpeg']['compile_flags']`の初期値の配列に `"--enable-static"`のみを追加するような書き方はできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookbookで定義済みのAttributeは、同形式であればマージされます。
詳しい挙動は次のリンクでAbout Deep Merge内のAddition項にあります。

http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#about-deep-merge

node用jsonだとどうだったか忘れましたが、RoleかEnvironmentで定義すれば次の内容だけで追加扱いになります。

```
ffmpeg": {
    "compile_flags": [
    "--enable-static"
    ]
  },
```